# Password Verfification for numbers and special characters

Tags: python

I am trying to create a user login system program. I am trying to make sure the password must have at least 10 characters which I have done, but I'm having trouble making sure it has at least two numbers and only underscore as a special character. I have seen some solutions about numbers and I don't get them and they rarely have at least 2 digits.

Here is my code:

```
print("Welcome ")
print('')
print('New users should enter Sign to create an account')
print('')
print('')

username = input('Enter your Username:   ')
if username == 'Sign':
    while True:
        usernames = ['Dave','Alice','Chloe']#A list that stores usernames
        create_user = input('Enter your new username:   ')
        if create_user in usernames:
            print('This user name has been taken .Try again')
            continue
        else:
            break
    usernames.append([create_user])
    while True:
        create_pass = input('Enter your your user password:   ')
        passwords = []#A list thst stores password
        pass_len = len(create_pass)
        if pass_len < 10:
            print('Your password must be at least 10. Try again')
            continue
        else:
            print('')
            print('You are now a verified user.')
            print('Run the application again to re-login.')
            print('Thank You')
            break

else:
    password = input('Enter your password')
    print('Visit www.bitly/p8?. to continue')
```

Comment: Requiring special characters is good. Restricting which special characters are allowed is bad, and generally unnecessary. The more you constrain the allowed set, the less work is required to brute-force a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not wanting to use regex, you could add some simple logic like this:

```
num_count = 0
for character in create_pass:
    if character.isdigit():
        num_count += 1
if num_count < 2:
    print('You must have at least 2 numbers in your password')
```

Comment: Thank you so much .This worked perfectly for the digits.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it. You can check for the underscore with `in` and use regex to search for the numbers.

```
import re

test = 'hisod2f_1'

underscore = '_' in test
twonums = len(re.findall(r'\d', test)) >= 2

if underscore and twonums:
    # your logic
```

Comment: Thank you it works but how will I do it for just only one underscore input

Comment: @daliseiy You can do it with the same way with the regex expression but replace `\d` with `_`